# How to add go-cross to Yocto SDK? Or otherwise compile Go for Yocto on other machines?

Tags: go, yocto, bitbake

I have been using the Yocto SDK to compile C and C++ code for Yocto so that every machine does not need the 150GB+ Bitbake environment. Yocto version is 2.4 (Rocko)

Now I would like to have the same functionality for Golang, but I can't figure out how to do it.

If I'm on the Bitbake machine, I can call the binary arm-arch-gnueabi-go binary found under the directory tmp/work/x86_64-linux/go-cross-arm/ to compile code. But if I copy those binaries to another machine, it links to libraries with hard-coded paths on the Bitbake machine so that won't work.

Is there a way to include arm-arch-gnueabi-go in the SDK when I run populate_sdk on the image? Or is there another easy way to compile Go for the target on other machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the following lines in `local.conf` file or image recipe:

```
TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK_append = " \
    packagegroup-go-cross-canadian-${MACHINE} \
"

TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK_append = " \
    ${@multilib_pkg_extend(d, 'packagegroup-go-sdk-target')} \
"
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.  While it does build a compiler for the sdk, the sdk is still missing the wrapper in `$SDKSYSROOT/usr/bin` to set GOROOT and call the compiler, which is in `$SDKSYSROOT/lib/go/bin/go`.  Also the all the go source files aren't present so it's not possible to compile anything.